# How to add additional information in a neural network other than putting as input data?

Tags: neural-network

I am trying to use a neural network to predict final concrete strength. I have used material properties of concrete as input data. Now if I want to add some additional information like early age strength, is there any way to put them in the hidden layer? I mean other than using as input data?

Comment: @ Ayesha Munira Chowdhury...can you let me know how did you finally add additional input to the network without additional input data ? What did you do finally? I am working on similar stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If your inputting data, it will always be an input :). But it is definitely possible to add in certain inptus after the first hidden layer. But what is your reasoning behind this? Why would you want this?

You should just input all your data in the first layer, let the neural network figure out how to use the data effectively itself. The neural network is like a black box, you put something in and something comes out - don't interfere too much by adding seperate inputs to the hidden layers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :) My Professor wants me to work on connecting Bayesian theory with Neural Networks.I have previously used concrete material properties as input data and received final concrete strength as output. Recently, I used early age concrete strength as additional input data, and that way the neural network predicted the final strength better than before. But then my Professor said that it's too obvious that any neural network with more input data would preform better. That's why I was asking if there's any way to put additional information other than putting as input data.

Comment: Ask what the professor has in mind.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I finally worked out something recently. :)